# Wavefunction collapse in Stern-Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

Consider silver atoms coming from an S(X) apparatus, after S(X) apparatus we place an S(Z) apparatus

$$
|\mathrm{SX+}\rangle= \frac{1}{2}|\mathrm{SZ+}\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|\mathrm{SZ-}\rangle,
$$

Action of $\hat{S}_z$ operator collapses the wave state to $|\mathrm{SZ+}\rangle$ or $|\mathrm{SZ-}\rangle$, but action of operator on $|\mathrm{SX+}\rangle$ can be mathematically represented as

\begin{align}
\hat{S}_z|\mathrm{SX+}\rangle & = \hat{S}_z\frac{1}{2}|\mathrm{SZ+}\rangle +\hat{S}_z\frac{1}{2}|\mathrm{SZ-}\rangle,
\\
\Rightarrow \qquad
\hat{S}_z|\mathrm{SX+}\rangle & = \frac{h}{4\pi}\frac{1}{2}|\mathrm{SZ+}\rangle -\frac{h}{4\pi}\frac{1}{2}|\mathrm{SZ-}\rangle, 
\end{align}
which can be normalised as $|\mathrm{SX-}\rangle$ state.

So my doubt is action of operator on a wave function collapses wave function to any of the eigen states or transforming the wavefunction to $|\mathrm{SX-}\rangle$ state?

Comment: see here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: measurements are not unitary or deterministic operations, and hence they objectively make information about the previous quantum state irretrievable, even in principle

Comment: I've done a starting round of formatting edits to get your post marginally readable, as far as allowed by your initial notation.

Comment: thanks for the help Emilo Pisanty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your core misconception is here:

> Action of $\hat{S}_z$ operator collapses the wave state to $|\mathrm{SZ+}\rangle$ or $|\mathrm{SZ-}\rangle$

This is incorrect. **Measurement** of the observable $S_z$ will collapse the wavefunction to one of its eigenstates, but that measurement is **not** modelled by acting with the operator $\hat{S}_z$ on the wavefunction. Instead, if you want to model the collapse, you use one of the two hermitian projection operators
\begin{align}
\hat{\Pi}_{z,+} & = |\mathrm{SZ+}\rangle \langle \mathrm{SZ+}|, \\
\hat{\Pi}_{z,-} & = |\mathrm{SZ-}\rangle \langle \mathrm{SZ-}|
\end{align}
(in the sub-optimal notation used in [v2 of your answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/474174/2) as the cleanest rendition I could do of your initial text; for clarity, here $\hat{S}_z |\mathrm{SZ\pm}\rangle = \pm \frac12 \hbar |\mathrm{SZ\pm}\rangle$.) If the measurement outcome is $S_z = +\frac12\hbar$, the projective measurement is the replacement $|\psi \rangle \mapsto \hat{\Pi}_{z,+} |\psi⟩$ (with a suitable normalization constant), and similarly for $S_z = -\frac12\hbar$.

Your observation that
$$
\hat{S}_z |\mathrm{SX+}\rangle = \frac12 \hbar |\mathrm{SX-}\rangle
$$
is correct but it is in no way contradictory or in conflict with any other parts of the formalism.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated [elsewhere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/474148/36194), not all operators transform a state into a linear combinations of eigenstates.  Instead of $\sigma_z$ consider the operator 
$\hat \Pi_{+,z}=\vert {+}\rangle_z {_z\langle} {+}\vert$.  This will transform the $\vert {+}\rangle_x$ eigenstate to 
$$
\vert {+}\rangle_z {_z\langle} {+}\vert {+}\rangle_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\vert {+}\rangle_z\, ,
\tag{1}
$$
which is a single state and not a linear combinations of eigenstates of $\sigma_z$.  Indeed $(1)$ shows how the state collapses to a particular eigenket.

Note that 
$$
\Pi_{+,z}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&0\end{array}\right)
$$ is still a perfectly valid operator.